# There is no model for a contradiction M $\models \phi \land \lnot \phi$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be  a languague. How can I show that there is no model ($L$-structure) $M$ for a contradiction?

M $\models \phi \land \lnot \phi$

It seems very intuitive to me but how do I prove it?

Comment: Satisfiability and consistency are the same thing.

Comment: I just closed as a duplicate. Let me know if the answer in the linked question does not resolve your question.

Comment: $\phi$ must be a *closed* formula, else the empty model could satisfy $\phi\land\lnot \phi$.